# Debugging freeze in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, debug

I am experiencing frequent hangs while typing in omnibox (location bar).

There was similar kind of issue(segfaulted) earlier too which was a widespread bug. It happened due to compiling chromium against newer version of gcc.

I am experiencing the similar issue now. The only difference is that the whole chrome completely freezes when I am typing stuff in location bar & the autocomplete dialog that opens below the location-bar also remains open in the freezed state.

Then, I have to actually kill the process by doing

$killall chromium

2 times to kill the chromium. What can I do to debug the issue?

Looking in the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxDebugging#Core_files), I managed to send the SIGABRT signals to all the processes of chrome when it was hanged. Now, I don't know where to find the DUMPS. Where do I look for it? I want to submit the bug on code.google.com but I can't do that until I find the core dumps.

I even tried posting on the [project page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139485), no replies yet.

Comment: First test if using a new, empty profile fixes it. If so, then run Chromium with a copy of the original profile, and clear out the history (from the beginning of time) and see if it still does it. If not, then it’s because you have too much history and Chromium is unable to read, parse, and search it fast enough. If it does still happen, then it’s something else, so put the backup profile back and test with an official copy of Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

- first of all disable: 'Enable Instant for faster searching' in your settings,
- you can use strace debugger (or alternative to your OS) e.g. `strace -f chrome`
- or attach to it, when it's already frozen (`strace -fp PID`),
- try to run Chromium from the terminal, it'll report you the errors and find the right bug for it,
- try to compile it using different compiler (i.e. gcc if you used cc or opposite), sometimes it helps because of some bugs which nobody can find it,
- there is option to run Chromium in recovery mode (disable all add-ons) - try it,
- go to about:about and see what you can find interesting,
- compile chromium with debug parameters (-g and without optimization) and run via gdb debugger or generate core file to check the backtrace why it crashed
- probably it's a duplicate bug, so look for bugs using different keywords like: Instant freeze